# How many complex numbers satisfy $z\bar{z}=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> How many complex number satisfy $$z\bar{z}=1$$

---

Edit:

How about  $$zz^*=1$$

Comment: Write $z=a+bi$ and what equation in $a,b$ do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by $zz*=1$=

Comment: I guess $z^*$ is physics notation for the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infinitely many. If $z=x+iy$, $z\overline{z}=(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^{2}+y^{2}=|z|^{2}$, so you're asking how many $z$ satisfy $|z|=1$, which is every $z$ on the unit circle.

Answer (score 5):

As many complex numbers as there are on the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: Second spite downvote I have gotten in two days. Hopefully this isn't a common thing...

Comment: Upvoted to spite them! Also, *this answer is useful...*